# popViewControllerAnimated:YES doesn't work

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I'm writing a unit test and I find popViewControllerAnimated:YES doesn't work.

```
(void)testNavi {
  UINavigationController *navi = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
  UIViewController *controllerA = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *controllerB = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  [navi pushViewController:controllerA animated:NO];
  [navi pushViewController:controllerB animated:NO];
  [navi popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  XCTAssertEqual(navi.topViewController, controllerA);
}
```

If I change [navi popViewControllerAnimated:YES] into [navi popViewControllerAnimated:NO], it works. I don't know why.

Comment: You can't push a view controller while pushing a view controller.  When it's not animated, there's no time requirement for the push animation and the push of A has finished before you push B.  Otherwise, weirdness happens and controllerB probably doesn't get pushed.  Then, when you pop, you're really popping A off the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better to call popViewControllerAnimated after view was created. So you may make subclass of NavigationController and implements it like this.

```
- (void)init {
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
      UIViewController *controllerA = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
      UIViewController *controllerB = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
      self.viewControllers = @[controllerA, controllerB];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear {
   [self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the animation happens asynchronously on another thread. The animation to pop the view controller takes a small amount of time, but the test assertion is made before the animation has completed, so the `topViewController` has not changed yet.

The best way to test this it to mock the `UINavigationController` and verify that `popViewController:YES` is called.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem testing `pushViewController` when the push is animated.

I was able to solve this by wrapping my assertion in this handy [`delay`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift/24318861#24318861) function from matt.

When introducing a delay in your test, it is necessary to use expectations to ensure the assertions are checked. Otherwise, the test completes before the delay code executes, resulting in a passed test that did not check your assertions!

```
// code to push the view controller goes here...

// set up the expectation
let expectation = expectationWithDescription("anything you want")

// now, assert something about the navigation controller 
// after waiting 1/10th second for the animation to finish
delay (0.1) {

    // for example: Navigation controller should have the 
    // expected number of view controllers
    XCTAssertEqual(1, navigationController.viewControllers.count)

    // if we get this far, then assertions passed and we must
    // fulfill expectations to pass the test
    expectation.fulfill()
}

// wait longer than the delay value, so the code in the delay closure
// has time to finish
waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(0.2, handler: nil)
```